# Using addresses of convenience variables in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Sometimes I come across functions that I want to call in my debugging that take a pointer as an argument and change the contents that are pointed to.
Example:

```
int doFoo(int a, double* b)
```

I would like to call this function from gdb, but don't have a `double*` lying around. Is it possible to do this with convenience variables? Simply calling

```
set $foo = 1.0
call doFoo(0, &($foo))
```

does not work.

Comment: If you don't have the `double` to act on "lying around", what purpose does calling `doFoo()` serve at that point? I'm confused.

Comment: Call `malloc` to create a variable. I don't think it is possible with convenience vars because they are in the GDB address space and not the target process address space.

Comment: @devSolar e.g. you return a value but you also bass a bool pointer that reflects whether the function call was successful

Comment: std::optional, an exception, some kind of signaling return value (like -1), or even an error code by reference... but a *bool* by reference? I don't like it.

Comment: @devSolar We are talking about C here, not C++, so there is no std::optional and it is a pointer, not a reference. This is quite common in some codes, where your function will return a return code, and you pass a bool pointer, that reflects, e.g. if a solution was stored.

Comment: @Leon: Sorry, I am "thinking" C++ most of the time. I'd still go for a full-blown `errno_t` or something instead of a bool, so you get an inkling of *what* did go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
set var $foo = &{1.0}
call doFoo(0, $foo)
p *$foo
```

Using `{}` makes GDB allocate a single item double array within the process's memory.
Note that without `&` in the assignment, evaluating `$foo` will return a new address every time.